# GNOME 3: Changing datetime format for lock screen?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3

I'm using GNOME Shell 3.22.3 on Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

I've edited the settings for the way time and date is displayed in the Status bar using the excellent Datetime format extension. However, I haven't been able to find any way to configure the way the time and date is displayed when I lock the computer. It's always:

> HH:MM:SS
>
> weekday, DD month

I suppose this is set by my locale somehow, as the weekday is indeed displayed in my local language as set for the OS.

I'd like to change this, for example removing the leading zero. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: The date format is hardcoded in [`js/ui/screenShield.js`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/screenShield.js): `let dateFormat = Shell.util_translate_time_string(N_("%A, %B %d"));` so you cannot change it unless you're willing to write a shell extension...

Comment: I see. I'm wondering why they hardcoded the date to display with a comma after the weekday, which is incorrect in my language. Oh, well. Nothing to do about it then, I guess. And @K7AAY, I will do so, thank you.